# Можно ли добавить событие v-on:click с помощью jQuery и обработать его во vue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Есть код html

```
<button id='qwerty'>qwerty</button>
```

Далее в javascript

```
$('#qwerty').attr('v-on:click', 'testMethod');
```

Как (и можно ли вообще) обработать событие testMethod во VueJS?

**Это нужно для этого:** Для построения дерева категорий использую эту библиотеку [mbraak.github.io/jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree) и хочу при клике на категорию с помощью VueJS и VueResourse получать товары из выбранной категории. Но для этого нужна директива v-on:click

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать на чём-то одном?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С такой задачей `vue` прекрасно справится и без `jquery`. Например, [вот](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html) реализация древовидного меню из оф. документации. *(Даже объекты с данными вроде как идентичны.)*

По вашему вопросу, можно например воспользоваться [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), при клике на элемент, у которого нет `v-on:click`

```js
$('#qwerty').on('click', function(evt) {
  $('#new').trigger('click');
});


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#new',
  methods: {
    testMethod: function(e) {
      console.log('Вызвали testMethod!');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<button id="qwerty">Нет v-on:click</button>
<button id="new" v-on:click="testMethod">Есть v-on:click</button>
```